# Basic SQL Modelling question

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design, relational-database, modeling

I am facing a situation where I need to reference different types of data.

Put straight it is a notification system where users can be notified about new comments on a webpage they follow or replies to comments they follow.

I have the following (reduced) Layout

Table: comments

```
comment_id (int) PRIMARY # primary key
entry_id (int) NULL # id of the webpage (entry), null if reply to  existing comment
comment_parentid NULL # parent id of comment if reply, null if root comment
```

Table: followers

```
user_id (int) # the user following
entry_id (int) NULL # webpage the user follows, null if it this entry is only for following replys to a specific comment
comment_parentid NULL # comment the user follows replys to, null if the user if this following entry represents following of the complete post on the webpage (notification for all new comments)
```

As you see it only makes sense if exactly ONE of the fields in question (entry_id, comment_parentid) is populated.

I also have problems finding a primary key for the following table. Because primary keys cannot contain nullable fields.

Therefore I thought I make just one field called "parent_id" or "followed_item_id" and set an additional enum flag what kind of parent id it is.

So the following table would look like:

```
user_id (int) PRIMARY 
followed_item_id (int) PRIMARY
followed_item_type ENUM('entry','comment') PRIMARY
```

Applied the same modeling technique the comments table would look like:

```
comment_id (int) PRIMARY # primary key
comnent_parentid_type ENUM('entry','comment') # parent id type. entry or comment.
comment_parentid (int) # parent id representing comment or entry
```

But I remember that I once had a Problem where I wanted to do something similar but there were very good arguments against it. I just cant remember and can't find the post.

So what is a good way to structure this kind of data?

Maby two tables that I both select with a UNION statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The argument against the "combo" table is that you can't have any referential integrity and you'll have to manage any cascading deletes yourself.

Seems like making two table would work, e.g. followed_entries and followed_comments.

Good luck.